# Import certificates using command line on Windows

Tags: powershell, ssl, certificate

I need to import a certificate file to `Trusted Root Certification Authorities` store, to get rid of an SSL warning when visiting my local website. The way I currently do it is lengthy: use Google Chrome → Settings → Advanced → Privacy and security → Manage certificates → Trusted Root Certification Authorities → Import...

[image]

It looks like some sort of Windows snap-in rather than a custom window of Chrome. This is dumb to do all these steps just to import a 1KiB certificate file. Can I do it on PowerShell, so that this action can be automated via script? Or at least how can I open the above window without Google Chrome?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If you are on a current version of Windows, you can use [PowerShell cmdlets](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/import-certificate?view=win10-ps):

```
Import-Certificate -FilePath "C:\CA-PublicKey.Cer" -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\Root
```

otherwise use [certutil](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/certutil):

```
certutil.exe -addstore root c:\capublickey.cer
```

Comment: Haven't test `certutil.exe`, but `Import-Certificate` works. Btw, what is the difference between `cert:\CurrentUser\Root` and `Cert:\LocalMachine\Root`? I am not familiar with Windows shell scripting.

Comment: @Livy - as the names suggest `CurrentUser` is the certificate store only for the currently logged-on user, `LocalMachine` is computer-wide, and those certificates can be used by all users.

Comment: So that's why I can no longer use the Certificates window above to remove it, as it requires administrative permission. I think I will add it to `cert:\CurrentUser\Root` next time.

Comment: @Livy because these are two different stores. The same utility can be used - in principle - to interact with the certificate store, but `certmgr.msc` is hardwired to the "current user" trust store. If you want any of the others, use `mmc.exe` and add the appropriate snap-in wired to an alternative trust store.

Comment: how can I use `certutil.exe` to add a certificate available in a URL?

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira - You should ask a new question and explain what you mean. A URL doesn't contain a certificate.

Comment: @PeterHahndorf I meant if I have on my server a direct link to the public certificate file `http://exemple.com/direct/path/to/capublickey.cer`

Comment: This works for Chrome, but not for Firefox.

Comment: @PeterHahndorf You can make a bat for windows, where you download the file with the bitsadmin command, after that, you can run the command to add to the windows store .

Answer (score 1):

`certutil -p "**password**" -importpfx Root "**ca-File.p12**"` worked for me from cmd line.