# JRE Keystore - Can't import certificate in user keystore (wrong password)

Tags: java, jre

I have an issue while importing certificate in users keystore for Java. (in appdata\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\Security).

I already have made scripts to add certificates to the "machine" keystore (in C:\Program Files...) and those works using the default password "changeit". But if I try to use this password (or changeme, which is for Mac OS IIRC), I can't list or import certificate in users keystore, for example trusted.certs and trusted.cacerts. Is there another "default password" for those?

Here is an example of the command I used :

```
.\keytool.exe -import -file C:\temp\CACERT_G3.cer -keystore "C:\Users\username\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\trusted.cacerts" -v -storepass "changeit"
erreur keytool : java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.KeyStore.load(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password verification failed
        ... 8 more
```

(The reason of this requirement is that we have a problem with an app that ignores certicate when we put them in the machine keystore, but if a user manually add the cert is in keystore with the Control Panel GUI, it works. So we have to deploy that solution to 18k+ users)

Answer (score 0):

The **java** User trusted.cacerts store is blank by default, like:

```
keytool -list -storepass "" -keystore .\path\to\Sun\Java\Deployment\Security\trusted.certs
```

But it is also in user-space, so any user could change the password, delete the keystore, etc.

---

However, you mention using the Control Panel GUI, certmgr.msc (User) or certlm.msc (System), which manages the **windows** trust store. These are *separate* locations, but are used for the same thing

Java can use the windows store with options like `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=WINDOWS-ROOT`, though there are some [other settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68730556/7411885) required, depending on your configuration.

Importing certificates into the windows trusted ca certs would be done with different tools like group policy, cmd (certutil.exe), or [powershell](https://superuser.com/a/1506481/673426), for example

Comment: I think OP meant the _Java_ Control Panel, which through 8 at least (and IIRC 10) does among other things manage the java-deployment store (not the Windows one).

Comment: Exactly, thanks for the clarification @dave_thompson_085!

And sadly, even on a "brand-new" store, the keytool...tool...doesn't work. If I try to use the parameter -storepass "", it return an error saying that storepass expect a value. And if I try to manually left it blank (on prompt), it asks for a PWD again :(